# SpotFire - I cant select markers/points on my line chart

Tags: spotfire

Im having issues with my line chart where I cant seem to select my markers or do any kind of selection on my line chart. I think it has to do with this ["Current Filtering"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYxNA.png) status on my line chart. if that is the case how do i remove it? if its not the case any suggestions. Thanks